What are the approximate dimensions of the liquid oxygen tank and liquid methane tank on the Starship?
I would like to have an idea of ​​the cylindrical height and diameter of the Starship's liquid oxygen tank. Likewise, the Starship's liquid methane tank.

original:

Qual a dimensão aproximada do tanque de oxigênio líquido e do tanque de metano líquido na starship?
Gostaria de ter uma ideia da altura cilíndrica e do diâmetro do tanque de oxigênio líquido da starship. Da mesma forma do tanque de metano líquido da starship.


Welcome to Stack Exchange! Most Stack Exchange sites require English, even if it is not very good English. I've added an English translation. (Bem-vindo ao Stack Exchange! A maioria dos sites do Stack Exchange exigem inglês, mesmo que não seja um inglês muito bom. Adicionei uma tradução para inglês. Google translate)

Also, here in Space Exploration SE we should include some evidence of prior research in questions. People will ask "Where did you look first?" Maybe you can do a quick Google search to see if you can find some information? Thank you! (Além disso, aqui no Space Exploration SE, devemos incluir alguma evidência de pesquisa anterior nas perguntas. As pessoas perguntarão "Onde você olhou primeiro?" Talvez você possa fazer uma rápida pesquisa no Google para ver se consegue encontrar alguma informação? Obrigado!)

@Starship it's not uncommon here in Space SE to leave the original language and add a translation. There is no rule that says other languages can not also be present. Here in Space SE it's usually Russian, but there's Chinese as well, and probably some European languages (other than English) can also be found. The presence of Portuguese doesn't cause harm to the site. And who knows, maybe Google Translate didn't do a good job. Better to leave both the original and the translation.

SpaceX has not released the full specification and dimensions for Starship and the design is still likely to change in the next few years (eg stretched tanks). However some information is in the public domain and more can be calculated from the vast quantity of published pictures.
So the best you are likely to get is something like this:
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fpb0ypz366ck41.png
